# Find the sum of all positive two digit integers that are divisible by each of its digits?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As for this one, I think I could count the number by hand, eliminating the numbers that contain prime numbers. But best if you could use variables!

Comment: Hand-count is best here. We can't eliminate numbers that contain prime numbers: example, $36$ or $77$.

Comment: Alright, but what if I ask you to count five or six digit numbers

Comment: Then we certainly would want to develop some general machinery! Or, these days, write a quick Python program.

Comment: Ok, so we are now seeking help in compsci.

Comment: Nice question.Also,I think the question should be posted in the main body as well,so that a person can understand what the question is without ever having to read the title.You might want to eliminate the two digit prime numbers apart from 11.There are 20 of them in total.Also.all 2 digit numbers of the form 10k must agree with your restrictions.But I am not sure if a simple algorithm exists to compute the number by hand.